# Implementing IDisposable in an API

Tags: c#, .net, api, idisposable

I'm currently writing a fairly large API and am confused as to how I should be implementing IDisposable. In a simplified scenario:

I have a Socket in one of my classes (call it A), which will obviously need disposing of, however that class only has internal constructors and hence my user would only be able to create an instance of it by creating an instance of a higher level object (call it B) which would in turn instantiate an A and thus take ownership of the new object A.

My intuition suggests to make both objects A and B IDisposable so that when the user disposes of our owning object B in their application, A is disposed of and the socket gets correctly disposed of as well. However, since this is an API, it would allow my user to dispose object A and the socket without disposing of the owning object B and hence could cause themselves some major issues.

So how should I proceed? As far as I can see my only options are bad options:

1. Implement IDisposable as intuition would have it and tell my user not to be stupid in the documentation. (Very bad)
2. Implement IDisposable as intuition would have it but add some hideous disposal checking/exceptions throughout the application just in case (although in the case of my application disposing of whole subsections would be fatal to the application anyway).
3. Only implement IDisposable in object B and instead add an internal Dispose method to safely dispose of A and the socket. (seemingly the best idea)

I'm not really sure if I have any other options so I really hope someone can advise me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the option of "using" block ?  It would do the same thing by calling Idisposible internally

Comment: The obvious approach is to add an internal Close() method to A.  B can call it in its Dispose() method.

Comment: option 3 seems to be best

Comment: @DinoMyte Unfortunately the reference is a member variable not a local variable so I can't do that :(

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't you say that `A` needs to implement `IDisposable` as well since it's a public class that has disposable resources?

Comment: No, that only invites the client programmer to call it.  He shouldn't, B owns it.

Comment: @HansPassant Duh - of course - whatever _creates_ the object is responsible for disposing of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My intuition suggests to make both objects A and B IDisposable so that
>   when the user disposes of our owning object B in their application, A
>   is disposed of and the socket gets correctly disposed of as well.
>   However, since this is an API, it would allow my user to dispose
>   object A and the socket without disposing of the owning object B and
>   hence could cause themselves some major issues.

Make both implement `IDisposable` is probably the best idea and clearly illustrates the fact that the code instances need to be cleaned up. Instruct the consumer of the API to call `Dispose` on the root/owning object (B). To get around the issue of the consumer of the API accidentally also calling `Dispose` on the owned (A) instance you could do the following.

**Hide it**

Do not expose the owned reference A from root/owning object B or provide a limited number of pass through methods that call into the root and pass through to the owned instance and then back again. This is fine if you are talking about real limited number of methods/properties that will not change.

**Interfaces**

Wrap the socket access using a wrapper and interface (*I am assuming here that the socket is a .net [socket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) but if its your own object implementation around the socket class then your class is the wrapper already and no need to create another wrapper around that*). The wrapper should implement `IDisposable` and interface should only expose what you want the client to have access to. I am not sure where you create instances of the socket but they should be created by either the owned object OR using a factory pattern so that the owner relationship is established asap after creation. You can keep the class definition internal and only expose an interface to the API.

In my opinion this is the best way to do it and allows for flexible changes in the future if you need to extend your API.

```
public class Owner : IDisposable
{
    private SocketWrapper _wrapper;
    public ISocketWrapper SocketAccess { get { return _wrapper; } }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_wrapper != null)
            _wrapper.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface ISocketWrapper
{
    // exposed properties/methods
}


internal class SocketWrapper : ISocketWrapper, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // dispose socket
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiding it might be a little optimistic for my project unfortunately! Interfaces sound like a good route to go down actually, thank you :)

Comment: @JamJar00 - glad to help! Please don't forget to mark it as the answer when you have time. Also consider exposing your Owner object using interfaces as well if you have not already done so. The less you expose in concrete classes the better especially for those classes that have implemented behavior and are not entity (pure state holding) classes. It will lead to more maintainable code in the future with less chance of having to create breaking changes when you extend your API.

Comment: I was going to wait and see if any other answers came up but since you asked so nicely ;) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont want that api user disposes your socket, than just hide it (make some wrapper or something where socket is private).

Otherwise dispose is usually implemented like this so you can perform cascade dispose and you dont really mind if something was disposed already.

```
public class ComplexResourceHolder : IDisposable {

private IntPtr buffer; // unmanaged memory buffer
private SafeHandle resource; // disposable handle to a resource

public ComplexResourceHolder(){
    this.buffer = ... // allocates memory
    this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
        ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory
    if (disposing){ // release other disposable objects
        if (resource!= null) resource.Dispose();
    }
}

~ ComplexResourceHolder(){
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose(){
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

}

Code sample is taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can find more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to remember when implementing `IDisposable` is DO NOT dispose of `IDisposable` instances that you do not "own" (those which your class has not specifically created).

So, in your case, Option 3 would be advisable.